# How to track subscriptions to an RSS feed

Tags: analytics, rss

I have  RSS feeds on some of my sites and I'm wondering how I can track how many people are subscribing to them.

The obvious solution is to track the number of hits on the URL, but I don't feel like that gives a very clear picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a tool like [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com) which has [integration](http://www.gospelrhys.co.uk/2007/09/how-to-track-new-rss-subscribers-google-analytics-in-3-easy-steps.html) with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get reliable numbers. Doesn't mean I like it though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not an easy problem to solve on your own. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327677/standard-and-reliable-way-to-track-rss-subscribers) on StackOverflow for more details. Really, as Adam mentioned, your best bet is using FeedBurner.